# Which .jar files do I put where to use jersey with tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jersey, classpath

I've setup a pretty default apache2/tomcat7 server.

I've used Eclipse WTP to build a minimal servlet using jersey.  (just downloaded the latest jersey.)

When I deploy the servlet to tomcat, I get this error in the catalina.out file:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MetrixServer/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

As far as I can tell, this means that I should NOT copy all the jars from the api/ext/lib directories of jaxrs-ri into my project. BUT if I leave them out, the app crashes on load missing other classes.  (for example: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`)

So, I obviously do NOT have the correct .jar files in the correct places, but I haven't found any good instructions on exactly which ones go where!

Comment: Note that I've verified that my Eclipse is building with Oracle JDK 1.6, and Tomcat is using Oracle JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally figured it out.  There were MULTIPLE problems.

1) Tomcat was running under JVM 1.6, and one of the libraries I was using (from Jersey) required 1.7.

2) The web.xml that I used as an example was from jersey 1, but I'm using jersey 2 - and the package names used in the xml have changed.

3) Eclipse wouldn't let me use 1.7 for the servlet due to only having a 1.6 java facet.  I had to REMOVE the 1.6 JRE from Eclipse before the Facet code would find the 1.7 facet.

So, use all the libs from jersey, but make sure your web.xml does not have any com.sun.... entries in it.